# cast sdk web receiver and shaka v3.0.10

Tags: google-cast, google-cast-sdk

in the latest release notes for cast sdk it states they shaka player used has been upgraded to v.3.0.10 on march 31st 2021
https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/release-notes
however the js file at
http://www.gstatic.com/cast/sdk/libs/caf_receiver/v3/cast_receiver_framework.js
still loads shaka v2.5.16
the preview version at
https://www.gstatic.com/cast/sdk/libs/caf_receiver/preview/cast_receiver_framework.js
does indeed load shaka v3.0.10
If this has been released then surely the v3 versoin should load v3.0.10 or should i pick up the release version from a new path?
Thanks
J

Answer (score 0):

we found an issue at the last minute of release so had to rollback. We have a fix and the release started to roll out slowly to 100% over the week. Please do join the google group for release notifications/Updates. https://developers.google.com/cast/support#news_and_announcements